# Why do I get an AttributeError when trying to use BeautifulSoup's `.find` to find text in a page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website with BeautifulSoup but am having a problem.
I was following a tutorial done in python 2.7 and it had exactly the same code in it and had no problems.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import *


htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
title = (soup.title.text)

body = soup.find("Born").findNext('td')
print (body.text)
```

If I try to run the program I get,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Programs\World Population.py", line 13, in <module>
    body = soup.find("Born").findNext('p')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'
```

Is this a problem with python 3 or am i just too naive?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want `body = soup.find('body')`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `find` and `find_all` methods do not search for arbitrary text in the document, they search for *HTML tags.* The documentation makes that clear (my italics):

---

Pass in a value for name and you’ll tell Beautiful Soup to only consider *tags* with certain names. Text strings will be ignored, as will tags whose names that don’t match. This is the simplest usage:

```
soup.find_all("title")
# [<title>The Dormouse's story</title>]
```

---

That's why your `soup.find("Born")` is returning `None` and hence why it complains about `NoneType` (the type of `None`) having no `findNext()` method.

That page you reference contains (at the time this answer was written) eight copies of the word "born", none of which are tags.

Looking at the HTML source for that page, you'll find the best option may be to look for the correct span (formatted for readabilty):

```html
<th scope="row" style="text-align: left;">Born</th>
<td>
    <span class="nickname">Steven Paul Jobs</span><br />
    <span style="display: none;">(<span class="bday">1955-02-24</span>)</span>February 24, 1955<br />
</td>
```

Comment: what if you do want to find some arbitrary text in the html file?

Comment: @user391339, though the original question didn't call for it, you can just use the regular Python string search functionality (e.g., the string `find` or regex `search`) on the stringified soup doc, either pretty or non-pretty: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing

Answer (score 6):

The `find` method looks for tags, not text. To find the name, birthday and birthplace, you would have to look up the `span` elements with the corresponding class name, and access the `text` attribute of that item:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import *


soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs"))
title = soup.title.text
name = soup.find('span', {'class': 'nickname'}).text
bday = soup.find('span', {'class': 'bday'}).text
birthplace = soup.find('span', {'class': 'birthplace'}).text

print(name)
print(bday)
print(birthplace)
```

Output:

```
Steven Paul Jobs
1955-02-24
San Francisco, California, US
```

PS: You don't have to call `read` on `urlopen`, BS accept file-like objects.